# Inspection says: CANNON not defined using Cannon.js + Webstorm 8.0.1 (but code runs fine)

Tags: javascript, webstorm, inspection, cannon.js

Cannon.js: https://github.com/schteppe/cannon.js/blob/master/build/cannon.js

When using this javascript lib cannon.js in webstorm I get an webstorm-inspection problem.

(I am using the lib as shown in there examples: http://schteppe.github.io/cannon.js/examples/threejs_mousepick.html)

My Code:

```
var groundShape = new CANNON.Plane();
```

Now Webstorm underlines CANNON and the inspection says: "Unresolved Variable or type CANNON".

How can I fix this?

(Not hide this error, but instead make Webstorm aware of CANNON and enable autocomplete etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer webstorm support gave me:

editing the cannon.js and inserting:

```
/** @name CANNON */
```

just before

```
f.CANNON=e()
```

(this is within the first line of code of cannon.js, right now at character 266 in that line.)

The inspection error does go away this way. (But editing the lib isn't really what I was hoping for.)